# Rendering nested form for field with filter checking in Ruby on Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

As a new to Ruby on Rails, I have stuck to render the nested_form_for fields with a filter checking. The nested form model already has some data in it which is said to be default data. Now on editing the model I need to set read-only feature and don't want to set any remove link on those default data. There is a field in the model 'is_default' which actually said that record is default or not. So how can I filter only those data? Please can any one pull me out from this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Share how I have done this...
In my partial render file I use edit.js.erb which is actually required as I need to load all the thing using AJAX call. so in this part I have added extra JQuery code to set the readonly value and hide the remove anchor as well. Below is my code...

```
if('<%= @apps_event.is_std %>' == 'y' && '<%= @action %>' != 'create') {
  $("#eventFormContainer").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'form_standard'))%>");
  var stdAttrib = <%= @apps_event.apps_events_attributes.size %>
  var stdAttribStr = 'apps_event_apps_events_attributes_attributes_';
  for (var i=0; i < stdAttrib; i++) {
    if($('#' + stdAttribStr + i + '_is_std').attr('value') === 'y') {
        $('#' + stdAttribStr + i + '_name').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
        var selectValue = $('#' + stdAttribStr + i + '_attribute_type').attr('value');
        $('#' + stdAttribStr + i + '_attribute_type option').each(function() {
            if ( $(this).val() != selectValue ) {
                $(this).remove();
            }
        });
        $('#' + stdAttribStr + i + '_is_std').parent().children('a.remove_nested_fields').css('display', 'none');
    }
  }
}
else {
  $('#eventFormContainer').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'form_custom'))%>");
}
```

have fun... ;)